# Why does centripetal acceleration equals $v^2/r$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

I have found something on [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Tangential_and_centripetal_acceleration), but I don't understand why does the $v(t) \frac{\mathrm du_t}{\mathrm dt}$ equals with $\frac{v^2}{r} u_n$.

Comment: Are you talking about circular motion, I assume?

Comment: Yes, im talking about circular motion.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the acceleration, you need to know the parametric equation of position on a circular uniform motion.

```
r(t)=rcos(ωt)ux + rsin(ωt)uy (parametric equation of position on c.u.m.)
```

The velocity is a derivate of position:

```
v(t)=-rωsin(ωt)ux + rωcos(ωt)uy
```

The acceleration is the derivate of velocity:

```
a(t)=-rω^2cos(ωt)ux - rω^2sin(ωt)uy
```

In the c.u.m. the tangencial acceleration is zero because the module of velocity doesn't change. So, the total acceleration is equal a normal acceleration.

We can define the velocity using a tangencial unitary vector like:

```
ut = -sin(ωt)+ cos(ωt)
```

So, the velocity is equal:

```
v = ωr ut
```

We can define the acceleration using a normal vector like:

```
ur = -cos(ωt) - sin(ωt)
```

So, the acceleration is equal:

```
a = rω^2 ur
```

The angular velocity (ω) is equal to:

```
ω = v/r (we see it in the equation of linear velocity)
```

So,

```
an = rω^2 = r(v/r)^2 (replacing ω by the above equation) = v^2/r
```

Comment: Thanks :) Why did you choose omega*t?

Comment: I know that the parameteic equation of circle is x=rcos(t), y=rsin(t) from t=0...2pi

Comment: omega*t equals with 2pi if t=T(period time), right?

Comment: @Botond The angular position is:θ(t)= ωt+ θ0. You start in the zero degree/radian, so θo = zero. So, θ(t)= ωt. You replace in sin(θ(t)) and cos(θ(t)) by sin(ωt) and cos(ωt).

Comment: Thank you, finaly someone who help instead of voting down.

Comment: @Botond, the most likely reason that your question is voted down is that it isn't the first, nor the last, time it has been asked.  Those that *volunteer* their time here do grow weary of those that refuse to search the site for similar question and, instead, ask that someone answer essentially the same question once again.  But don't worry, the next one that asks your question will receive down votes too.